# [CLR Threading]When a thread pool thread blocks, the thread pool creates additional threads

Tags: multithreading, clr, threadpool

I see this in the book "CLR via C#" and I don't catch it. If there are still threads available in the thread pool, why does it create additional threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be poor wording.

On a given machine the threadpool has a good guess of the optimum number of threads the machine can run without overextending resources. If, for some reason, a thread becomes IO blocked (for instance it is waiting for a long time to save or retrieve data from disk or for a response from a network device) the threadpool can start up another thread to take advantage of unused CPU time. When the other thread is no longer blocking, the threadpool will take the next freed thread out of the pool to reduce the size back to "optimum" levels.

This is part of the threadpool management to keep the system from being over-tasked (and reducing efficiency by all the context switches between too many threads) while reducing wasted cycles (while a thread is blocked there might not be enough other work to task the processor(s) fully even though there are tasks waiting to be run) and wasted memory (having threads spun up and ready but never allocated because they'd over task the CPU).

More info on the [Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: For a long time I avoided thinking about them too. I had looked at stuff before but it wasn't until doing some work with Silverlight that I was forced to think about it more. Silverlight's service references generate proxy classes without synchronous calls. You have to do everything as events with callbacks. That's when I really started becoming interested in threads and their benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The book lied.

Threadpool only creates additional threads when all available threads have been blocked for more than 1 second. If there are free threads, it will use them to process your additional tasks. Note that after 30 seconds of thread idle, the CLR retires the thread (terminates it, gracefully of course).